# Laravel session not working with custom middleware

Tags: laravel, session, middleware

I was working with custom middleware and custom authentication for session checking and found that $request->getSession() or Session::get() is no longer working. 
In the user controller (after login), I'm using:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('custom_authenticate');
}
```

And in custom authentication controller (not using auth), I'm using:

```
Session::put('user_id', $user->id);
echo ">> " . Session::get('user_id');   // this gives the value stored in user_id
```

Here is my custom middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class CustomAuthenticate
{
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $userId = Session::get('user_id');

    if (!isset($userId)) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

In the middleware, I don't get anything from **Session::get()**

Here is my **Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'custom_authenticate' => \App\Http\Middleware\CustomAuthenticate::class
];
```

Comment: I test on my application with above code. I normally get $userId. Hmm..

Answer (score 0):

Check you have grouped that middleware in your routes.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'custom_authenticate'], function () {
        //list  of all controllers action
});
```

You can even change your middleware action as follows

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(session()->has('user_id')){
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);

}
```